# How multiple queries are handled connection wise within the same dbcontext instance

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, ef-core-6.0

How does the default implementation of dbcontext in EF core handle the connections for multiple sequential queries within same scope, when the scope is not wrapped within a transaction?

E.G.

1. Query some data.
2. Do some math
3. Query more data
4. Do more math
5. return the result

Wrapping the scope in a transaction should force it to use the same connection. Is the same behavior also applied without a transaction?

The best explanation I have found so far is here: "[Working with DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/working-with-dbcontext)", heading "Connections". This does not explicitly state, what the exact behaviour is, but from "reading between the lines" I understand that one query = one connection from the pool and after calling the execution method (e.g. ToListAsync, FirstAsync, etc.) the connection is returned to the pool right away.

Is my understanding correct or am I missing something?

Comment: What's the actual question? What you describe are bugs. A DbContext isn't a database connection, it's a Unit of Work and so *meant* to be short-lived. It doesn't even open a connection until one is needed.  If you use explicit transactions you break it. It doesn't support concurrent queries because *they aren't needed*.

Comment: I edited the question to better describe the question. The question is about sequential queries.

I understand, that the DbContext isn't a database connection. The connections are handled under the hood by the ADO.NET.
My question is about how the DbContext uses the connections, when multiple queries are done sequentially.

Comment: The behavior is going to necessarily be dependent on the underlying database client and connection pooling implementation and settings.

Comment: @HannesHärm why are you asking? It matters. Yes, a different connection is used but that costs nothing because it's taken from ADO.NET's connection pool. Connection pooling isn't an EF feature. If you think you have pooling issues, you'd have the same problems if you used `using(var connection=new MyWhateverConnection(...))`. This is such a fundamental feature though that all providers get it right - except maybe Oracle's MySQL drivers. Which is why people use MySqlConnector instead of Oracle's Connector/.NET

Comment: Why are you asking about *multiple* queries? ORMs like EF Core will load an entire graph of related objects, not just a single type at a time. If you call `context.Books.Include(b=>b.Author)......ToListAsync()` EF will use the same connection to load all related objects, even if you use `AsSplitQuery()`

Comment: The point is that you *shouldn't* have to care about the connections. DbContext works disconnected using optimistic transactions, just like ADO.NET DataTables and DataSets.

Comment: If you are asking how a single instance of DbContext runs lots of queries in sequence, then the answer is the connection to the DB can be reused once the previous query has completed. Not really sure what more you need to know.

Comment: I am asking to better understand, how EF core works under the hood. "Just works" is not good enough of an understanding to me, sometimes this knowledge comes very handy.